# why i can not make an one dimensional matrix from file?

Tags: c

I think this program should print the number 4 , but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong ? I am actually trying to apply something similar for character matrices. I want my program to read characters from an archive and save them in a one dimensional matrix.any ideas ? (I am using dev-c by the way ). furthermore the archive is really big (150 mb).. so I will need a really big matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    char c;
    int matrix[10000000];
    long long  int i; i=0;
    int a;a=0;

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("experiment.txt","r");

    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        matrix[i]=a;
        a=a++;
    }

    printf("%d",matrix[4]);                   

    fclose(fp);                                 
    exit(0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What?  'but it doesn't' - well what does it print?  Why 'a=a++' - are you trying to be confusing?

Comment: iostream and string are c++. `a = a++` is undefined behavior. You don't use your `char c` anywhere. `main()` should be `int main()`. You don't read characters anywhere in your program

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
a = a++;
```

to

```
a++;
```

Remember that the expression `a++` is post increment operator, it **doesn't equal** to `a + 1`, it will increase `a` **after** the expression, but in other hand `a` is assigned to the result of the expression, which is `0`, so it's an undefined behaviour.

**PS:** actually you don't read anything from file in this code, but the question is about reading a matrix from file?